# Feature Engineering for missing values over test and train data together or separately

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I note 2 styles of feature engineering. Hence my question to confirm what I think is best practice by an example as follows:

- If we need to fill in missing values (as opposed to discard the observation,

  - then in the case of imputing missing Age

    - I would do this over the whole data set before splitting into train and test, etc.
- However, I see example of persons doing this over the test and train data individually. Surely this is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to use an out-of-sample validation or test set is to mimic the real application of your machine learning model: releasing it into the wild. As far as you’re concerned, once you split the data, only the training data exist.

Whatever method you use to fill in missing values or engineer features in the training data, go do that for the out-of-sample observations.

You don’t really even think of the out-of-sample data as a set. While you won’t program this way, think of it as making sequential predictions. You have this awesome machine learning model, and a customer comes to you with new data, desperate to know your prediction. “Doc, what do you think?” Make your prediction, using what you’ve learned on the training data. Then move to the next observation that the next customer brings.

Comment: So, you think my idea to fill in gaps over all data is not the way to go. I am pretty sure on some coursera courses from memory, they do exactly that. I cannot follow your prose actually.

Comment: No, you don’t do all of it at the same time. Only the training data exist to you. You don’t get to see the exam questions while your studying, as an analogy.

Comment: OK, clear. Ok, but then how are the missing values in the test compensated for? Same calc but independently?

Comment: I am taking it that it is applied to both but independently.

Comment: For instance, if you do mean imputation and fill in all missing values with the mean $\bar{x}$ of your variable, use that same $\bar{x}$ on the out-of-sample data. Do not calculate a separate mean on the out-of-sample data.

Comment: Are you agreeing with me then? Yes I mean imputation. Without seeing the data on test you can impute. Is this what you mean? If so, then the answer needs changing.

Comment: If your mean value of $x$ is $5$ in-sample, if you want to do mean imputation for $x$ out-of-sample, use $5$, even if the mean value of $x$ out-of-sample is $4$.

Comment: OK, that is what I wanted to know. Cool.